# UIMA Ruta - comparing features of the Annotation

Tags: uima, ruta

There is a need to compare two numbers before creating an annotation. I've successfully managed to do it when numbers are expressed as digits.
Sample input:

> between 2-5 pm

Script:

```
DECLARE Annotation Hour (STRING value);
INT intVar1, intVar2;
(
    NUM{PARSE(intVar1)} 
    SPECIAL{REGEXP("-")} 
    NUM{PARSE(intVar1)}
)
    {(intVar1 < intVar2) -> CREATE(Hour, "value" = n1 + ":00-" + n2 + ":00")};
```

However, it's harder to follow the same logic while working with numerals (word numbers). Sample input:

> between two five pm

I have declared Cardinal Annotation to capture numerals:

```
DECLARE Annotation Cardinal (STRING value);
DECLARE Annotation Hour (STRING value);
INT intVar1, intVar2;

WORDTABLE CardinalsLoader = 'Cardinals.csv';
Document{-> MARKTABLE(Cardinal,1, CardinalsLoader, "value" = 2};
```

Cardinals.csv looks like this:

```
dct_token;value;
zero;0
one;1
two;2
three;3
```

So the challenge is to compare these Cardinals. Perhaps, there is somehow similar **PARSE** functionality for *features* of Annotations (I want to get the "value" feature of Cardinal Annotation and transform it into INT type). Is there a solution to this one or any workaround?

NOTE: I am using UIMA Ruta 2.2.1

Comment: Did you declare the `value` feature of `Cardinal` annotation as STRING on purpose? Unless there is no particular reason for that, you could declare it as INT and avoid any parsing by comparing the `value` features directly.
P.S. Consider upgrading the UIMA Ruta version (e.g. 2.8.0).

Comment: Hey there! Unfortunately, I have no chances for declaring it as INT and upgrading UIMA Ruta. At least for now

Comment: As of now, the `PARSE` condition in Ruta takes the covered text of the annotation as argument to parse. Parsing a feature of an annotation is unfortunately not supported. I will create an improvement request to address this feature for the next Ruta updates. As far as I'm concerned, I don't see any workaround for your issue at the moment.